# Ruby threading/forking with API (Sinatra)

Tags: ruby, multithreading, parallel-processing, sinatra, ruby-thread

I am using `Sinatra` gem for my API. What I want to do is when request is received process it, return the response and start new long running task.

I am newbie to Ruby, I have read about Threading but not sure what is the best way to accomplish my task.

Here my `sinatra` endpoint

```
  post '/items' do
     # Processing data
     # Return response (body ...)
     # Start long running task
  end
```

I would be grateful for any advice or example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that better way to do it - is to use background jobs. While your worker executes some long-running tasks, it is unavailable for new requests. With background jobs - they do the work, while your web-worker can work with new request.

You can have a look at most popular backgroung jobs gems for ruby as a starting point: `resque`, `delayed_jobs`, `sidekiq`

UPD: Implementation depends on chosen gem, but general scheme will be like this:

```
# Controller
post '/items' do
  # Processing data
  MyAwesomeJob.enqueue # here you put your job into queue
  head :ok # or whatever
end
```

In `MyAwesomejob` you implement your long-runnning task

Next, about Mongoid and background jobs. You should **never** use complex objects as job arguments. I don't know what kind of task you are implementing, but there is general answer - use simple objects.

For example, instead of using your `User` as argument, use `user_id` and then find it inside your job. If you will do it like that, you can use any DB without problems.

Comment: Thanks for answer, could you please provide example how it would look like in my case, I mean returning response and than adding background job or vice versa ? Thanks

Comment: And one more thing, I am using Mongoid to save objects how can I use it or pass the object to the Sidekiq ?

Answer (score 0):

Agree with unkmas.

There are two ways to do this.
Threads or a background job gem like sidekiq.

Threads are perfectly fine if the processing times aren't that high and if you don't want to write code for the worker.  But there is a strong possibility that you might run up too many threads if you don't use a threadpool or if you're expecting bursty http traffic.

The best way to do it is by using sidekiq  or something similar.  You could even have a job queue like beanstalkd in between and en-queue the job to it and return the response.  You can have a worker reading from the queue and processing it later on.